# Error in astroid 1.3.6 package while installing pylint for python 3.3.4

Tags: python, pylint

I'm trying to install pylint in a unix server. I know that there are two packages i need to install before installing pylint package.

1. astroid package
2. logilab-common package
3. at last pylint package

but while installing astroid im getting a weird syntax error. I have posted the error I'm getting below. Hot to install pylint module for my python?

Python Version: 3.3.4
astroid Version: 1.3.6
Server: Unix server

ERROR MESSAGES:

This is the output from astroid install:

> Extracting astroid-1.3.6-py3.3.egg to
>   /project/3rdParty_RH5/3rdParty_con_final/3rdParty/python-3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages
>   File
>   "/project/3rdParty_RH5/3rdParty_con_final/3rdParty/python-3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages/astroid-1.3.6-py3.3.egg/astroid/tests/testdta/python2/data/module.py",
>   line 32 
>       except ValueError, ex: 
>                        ^  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "/project/3rdParty_RH5/3rdParty_con_final/3rdParty/python-3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages/astroid-1.3.6-py3.3.egg/astroid/tests/testdta/python2/data/all.py",
>   line 7 
>       def func(): print 'yo' 
>                            ^  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "/project/3rdParty_RH5/3rdParty_con_final/3rdParty/python-3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages/astroid-1.3.6-py3.3.egg/astroid/tests/testdta/python2/data/module2.py",
>   line 78 
>       exec 'c = 3' 
>                  ^  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "/project/3rdParty_RH5/3rdParty_con_final/3rdParty/python-3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages/astroid-1.3.6-py3.3.egg/astroid/tests/testdta/python2/data/noendingnewline.py",
>   line 21 
>       print 'a' 
>               ^  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "/project/3rdParty_RH5/3rdParty_con_final/3rdParty/python-3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages/astroid-1.3.6-py3.3.egg/astroid/tests/testdta/python2/data/appl/myConnection.py",
>   line 1 
>       from **future** import print_statement  SyntaxError: future feature print_statement is not defined
>
> astroid 1.3.6 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Installed
>   /project/3rdParty_RH5/3rdParty_con_final/3rdParty/python-3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages/astroid-1.3.6-py3.3.egg
>   Processing dependencies for astroid==1.3.6  Searching for six==1.5.2 
>   Best match: six 1.5.2  Processing six-1.5.2-py3.3.egg  six 1.5.2 is
>   already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Using
>   /project/3rdParty_RH5/3rdParty_con_final/3rdParty/python-3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages/six-1.5.2-py3.3.egg
>   Searching for logilab-common==0.63.2  Best match: logilab-common
>   0.63.2  Processing logilab_common-0.63.2-py3.3.egg  logilab-common 0.63.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth  Installing pytest script to /opt/atseintl/3rdParty/python-3.3.4/bin
>
> Using
>   /project/3rdParty_RH5/3rdParty_con_final/3rdParty/python-3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages/logilab_common-0.63.2-py3.3.egg
>   Finished processing dependencies for astroid==1.3.6

Comment: those are actually errors in astroid's test data and doesn't seems to prevent your installation, so you should be able install pylint.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have installed pylint, but I'm not able to run the pylint command. when i run it im getting,-------

-bash-3.2$ pylint simple test_manageapp.py       
    -bash: pylint: command not found
 -------
this error. Can you please tell me why is this happening? How should I make it run?